# Issue with Combobox

Tags: python, tkinter

excuse the greeness. Trying to build GUI where option selected from Combobox populates text box. Nothing happening. First time programming so appreciate i have made a lot of errors here.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import scrolledtext

# function to display course selected
def courseDisplay():
    box = course.get() 
    print(box)

# Create instance
win = tk.Tk() 
win.resizable(130,130)   
win.title("RaceCourse GUI")

# create combobox
course = tk.StringVar()
courseChosen = ttk.Combobox(win,width=60,textvariable=course,state='readonly')   
courseChosen['values'] = ("Choose a course","Ascot", "Bath", "Chester")
courseChosen.grid(column=5, row=1,rowspan = 3, columnspan = 3,padx = 300, pady = 40)
courseChosen.current(0)
courseChosen.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", courseDisplay)

# create scrolled Text control    
scrolW  = 46
scrolH  =  10
box = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(win, width=scrolW, height=scrolH, wrap=tk.WORD)
box.grid(column=5, row=8, columnspan=3,padx = 300,pady = 10)

# Start GUI

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: _nothing_ happens? Or do you get an error when you change the combobox?

Answer (score 2):

Since function `courseDisplay` is called when some event occurs on combobox (namely, when some option is selected), it should accept one variable (usually called `event`). So, your function should look like this:

```
def courseDisplay(event=None):
    box = course.get() 
    print(box)
```

Of course, You should add another logic for showing test in textbox instead of `print`.